# dual Ubuntu 20.04 and graphics card

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04

I use Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with Windows 10. I need to run a python code (Pytorch-CUDA) on GPU but I found that I can't access graphics card on Ubuntu.

After this command : `lspci | grep VGA`, I just get this:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)`

Do I need to install NVIDIA drivers and it may solve the problem?
I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with that, because it's a bit confusing for me.

Edit: the output of this command: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 630
        Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Comment: Which Nvidia graphics card do you have?  Is this a laptop with "hybrid graphics" or a desktop computer with a dedicated GPU?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just edited it

Comment: @Nmath , NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, It's an MSI laptop

Comment: Research "hybrid graphics" as it pertains to your specific model laptop. The implementation is not consistent between devices.